# how to add foreign key in a table using insert and select statement?

Tags: mysql, select, insert, foreign-keys

i have tried this

```
INSERT INTO PARENT (FamilyID,userName, email, password)VALUES ((SELECT FamilyID FROM 'FAMILY' WHERE familyName=‘Idiots13’),'abc12','abc12@gmail.com', 'abc123#’);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''FAMILY' WHERE familyName=â€˜Idiots13â€™), 'deeepak13','deepak13@gmail.com', '' at line 3
```

please help!!

Comment: escape the quotes around FAMILY, or change to backticks or whichever your sql db uses (could be [ ])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used wrong type of quotes around `‘Idiots13’`, you need to use `'` instead of `‘` and `’`.

The same problem is also in the ending quote of `'abc123#’`.